# Trying to make a simple type math game for my 4 year old.

Tags: java

Trying to make a simple type math game for my 4 year old.  Having issue with my first operation.  I am trying to generate to random numbers then have number 1 and number 2 displayed for him to answer.  Problem is println text - first number text - second number - text

Basic syntax i am trying to get to work:

```
    int SIDES = 6;
    int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * SIDES);
    int b = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * SIDES);
    System.out.println("What is " +a "+" +b "=");
```

That last line is not correct. Please help.

Comment: You're missing `+`s after the `a` and `b`.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Comment: `System.out.println("What is " +a+ "+" +b+ "=");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an addition operator for your String in `println`:

```
System.out.println("What is " + a "+" + b "=");
//                               ^ Missing '+' operator
```

So you should change it to this:

```
 System.out.println("What is " + a + "+" + b "=");
```